# User gets first x units of a product free, then has to pay per unit thereafter

Tags: 7, commerce

I am wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction. There is only a single product type on my site, however I want every user to get 1000 "point" credit every month. They can buy 1 product for each credit.

I am assuming some kind of checkout system is also necessary, but the payments only have to be through paypal or something similar.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to look at the *Userpoints API* (http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/userpoints) and possibly utilized *Rules* in conjunction with an eCommerce solution like *UberCart*.

Or, if you don't need to actually take payment in money at all, there is a Userpoints Contrib module for facilitating points in conjunction with downloads.

*userpoints-download*
Users lose or gain points when the download attachments (requires site to be configured with private download method).

Comment: Does installing a big module like ubercart affect the performance on my site if I only use a small portion of it?

Comment: UberCart itself is fairly modular, so you can disable aspects of its interface which you don't need, like Shipping, etc. if you have just digital products.